# document classification using keras - hierarchical sequence of digits

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, nlp, document-classification

I'm currently approaching a classification problem with the following situation:

The labels are always 5 digits long, e.g.:

```
99923 this is sample document one
56743 this is sample document two
...
```

where the first single digit stands for a certain category, every following digit for a subcategory and so on.

Currently I'm using Keras with the following settings:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, input_shape=(vocab_size,)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(num_labels))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Because my training data is limited (around 80k samples overall), I decided to use only the first digit to estimate the main-category and I got pretty good results with ~90% accuracy without any preprocessing which yet has to be done.

```
5 - this is sample of maincategory 5
9 - this is sample of maincategory 9
...
```

Now I wanted to approach a level further and use two digits to predict the main-category and the first subcategory. That brought me to the problem that there is often not a single sample for e.g. the combination "12".

```
51 - this is sample of maincategory 51
95 - this is sample of maincategory 95
...
```

I told Keras to only use the labels with at least 1 sample (knowing that this is crap) and got around 40 labels with an overall accuracy of 85% which seems to be pretty good given the fact that I've lost many samples.

**My question is**:

Can this kind of prediction be done more easily/efficiently? If I let my "two-digits" model predict an unseen sample out of a category which hasn't been trained, I would run into the problem of fitting a sample into a wrong category...

Can I solve this prediction problem using Keras?

Comment: Have you tried using one softmax layer per each level of categories, i.e. one layer predicts the category, another layer predicts sub-category, and so on?

Comment: Since I don't know how to achieve this - no, but it seems to be a good idea. I try to achieve the following: If I know, that my main-category is 9, the next prediction must be done dependently on that category, so: based on mc 9, which is the possible subcategory. Any ideas on code-level? Thanks in advance! @today

Answer (score 2):

Well, as I mentioned in the comments section, one idea that comes to my mind is to use a softmax layer for each category level in the hierarchy. For example for three categorical levels we have three classifier layers:

```
from keras.models import Model

inp = Input(shape=(vocab_size,))
x = Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(vocab_size,))(inp)
x = Dropout(0.3))(x)
x = Dense(128, activation='relu'))(x)

cat_1 = Dense(num_labels_cat1, activation='softmax')(x)
cat_2 = Dense(num_labels_cat2, activation='softmax')(x)
cat_3 = Dense(num_labels_cat3, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model(inp, [cat_1, cat_2, cat_3])
```

It is as though the information about all the categorical levels is encoded in the output of last non-classifier layer. So passing it to the specialized classifier layers enables the model to extract the information about the corresponding categorical level.

Note that this may or may not have good performance. You must experiment to find out. There is still room for improvement, though. For example, you can use `Embedding` layer and include Conv1D or LSTM layers in your model as well.

If you are not familiar with Keras Functional API you may want to read the [official guide](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/).

Comment: Thanks  - I will try that and get back with feedback.

Comment: Hi , I have a few question about your solution. I've read the guides for Keras - I'm definitely not an expert user but willing to learn. I can derive your overall idea from your code - but: Do you assume `num_labels_cat1 = 10` because the digits from 0 to 9 can occur and `num_labels_cat2 = 10` because the first subcategory is therefore equal and so on or is num_labels_cat2 = every combination of two digits? From which information does the model understand the dependency of the digits? I would be glad if you could explain it a little bit further. I'll leave any evaluation here for learnings.

Comment: @JulianGerhard Well, one way to think about it is like this: suppose we have 3 categories, so `num_labels_cat1=3`, and category #1 has 4 subcategories, category #2 has 8 subcategories, and category #3 has 2 subcategories. We can set the number of labels for the first subcategory to the maximum number, so `num_labels_cat2=8`. The learning process **might be able** to encode all the categorical information in the output of last non-classifier layer. Further, you can define a custom loss function to further penalize wrong classification (e.g. subcategory is correct, but category is incorrect).

Comment: @JulianGerhard Further, note that in the simplest case when you set the loss function to `categorical_crossentropy`, the loss values for each output layer (e.g. in the example above we have 3 output layers) will be summed together and the model tries to minimize this sum which corresponds to predicting all the categorical levels correctly. However, as I mentioned in my answer, you must experiment and tune the network properly (i.e. adjust the number of layers, number of units, initial value of learning rate, layers used, optimizer used, etc.) to find out whether this approach works or not.

Comment: Hi, I've thought about your suggestion the last days and played a little bit around with your approach. It doesnt seem like the net is getting the way out of it but another idea came to my mind - maybe you have an idea about hat. What if do the following: I train a "main"-model for predicting the first/main-category (which is done an works very well). For example purposes I'm now only following the trail for the mc "9". I now train a model for every subcategory following the 9 by only using the training data I have for "9 + subcategory" and continuing that for every combination that's possible

Comment: As far as I'm aware of, I would loose the interconnection between the categories and their subcategories with this implementation, but I have a separate model for every "case" happening that I can tune. If I get an unseen sample, I predict the main category that leads the path for the next model (model for first-subcategory-of-maincategory-x) and so on. I'm assuming that I can build small models and hold them in the RAM. What do you think about that approach (I hope I could clarify my idea).

Comment: @JulianGerhard Well, it may work but I think with this approach you need lots of training examples to be able to achieve a good accuracy, say at least 1k-10k examples for each sub-sub-category. At the end, it is very hard to give a definite answer and you must experiment to find out. However, I think having one model that does all the job might be a better approach since you fuse the information about all the categorical levels in one place and this makes your model more powerful. BTW, is this a public dataset that you are working on?

Comment: Probably you are right. I've sent you an email with further information. Any "solution" popping out of it is posted here.

Answer (score 0):

If each level of your labels are inter connected (or even has high dependency), then following approach might help to improve your model.

Adding the output of first level classifier output as input for next level classifier.

This helps your model to use the prediction on the higher level to lower level classification.

Comment: How would I achieve that after training?

Comment: since we are going to use predictions for sequential models, it should be the same during the test as well

Comment: Sorry but I dont get it currently though I have an idea of what you mean. Do you have an example of your solution?